# Kotlin Dokka - Error loading Package List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to generate a documentation from my Kotlin project using Dokka. I'm using the 0.9.17 version.

Here is my gradle configuration :

```
dokka {
    includes = ['../README.md']
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/outputs/doc"

    // Use to include or exclude non public members.
    includeNonPublic = false

    // Do not create index pages for empty packages
    skipEmptyPackages = true

    packageOptions {
        prefix = 'com.app.internal'
        suppress = true
    }
    // No default documentation link to kotlin-stdlib
    noStdlibLink = true
}
```

To generate the documentation, I use the command :

```
./gradlew dokka
```

But there is a problem (else I wouldn't ask to you ^^). The issue I encounter is :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dokka'.
> Guice provision errors:

  1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while loading package-list from ExternalDocumentationLinkImpl(url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/, packageListUrl=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/package-list)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.ExternalDocumentationLinkResolver.<init>(ExternalDocumentationLinkResolver.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.ExternalDocumentationLinkResolver.class(ExternalDocumentationLinkResolver.kt:28)
    while locating org.jetbrains.dokka.ExternalDocumentationLinkResolver
      for parameter 4 at org.jetbrains.dokka.DeclarationLinkResolver.<init>(DeclarationLinkResolver.kt:13)
    while locating org.jetbrains.dokka.DeclarationLinkResolver
      for parameter 0 at org.jetbrains.dokka.PackageDocs.<init>(PackageDocs.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.PackageDocs.class(PackageDocs.kt:12)
    while locating org.jetbrains.dokka.PackageDocs

  1 error
```

I'm not alone because [a bug is opened](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/213) and the reason is surely because I'm behind a proxy but I don't know how to fix this.

Do you have any idea ?